# How to remove quotes in suds-py3 requests

Tags: python-3.x, request, suds

I´m using suds-py3 to make requests to a service with complex arguments that requires numbers and texts. This is the code i´m trying:

```py
from suds.client import Client
url = <service_url>
parameter = <service_method_parameter>
method = <service_method>
client = Client(url)
parameter_object = client.factory.create(str(parameter))
```

Until here, i´ve created a dictionary of the values that the service asks that looks like this:

```py
parameter_object = {
        'codigoAmbiente': '',
        'codigoModalidad': '',
        'codigoPuntoVenta': '',
        'codigoSistema': '',
        'codigoSucursal': '',
        'cuis': '',
        'nit': ''
        }
```

So to make the request, i create another dictionary with the required values:

```py
request_dictionary = {
        'codigoAmbiente': 2,
        'codigoModalidad': 2,
        'codigoPuntoVenta': 0,
        'codigoSistema': 'AA5BB4CC3',
        'codigoSucursal': 0,
        'cuis': 'A1B2C3',
        'nit': 12343456
        }
```

Then i send the values to the service with the following code.

```py
for var, value in request_dictionary.items():
    parameter_object[str(var)] = value
request_response = getattr(client.service, method)()
print(request_response)
```

The problem is that the service sends back an error because of the quotes, it doesn´t recognise them. If i try to send a dictionary like the following:

```py
request_dictionary = {
        'codigoAmbiente': 2,
        'codigoModalidad': 2,
        'codigoPuntoVenta': 0,
        'codigoSistema': AA5BB4CC3,
        'codigoSucursal': 0,
        'cuis': A1B2C3,
        'nit': 12343456
        }
```

Python throws the error "NameError: AA5BB4CC3 is not defined".
How should my code look like so the request to the service is as intended?

Answer (score 0):

I´ve  made a mistake in my code. It wasn´t the quotes. The correct code is the following:

```py
from suds.client import Client
url = <service_url>
parameter = <service_method_parameter>
method = <service_method>
client = Client(url)
parameter_object = client.factory.create(str(parameter))
for var, value in request_dictionary.items():
    parameter_object[str(var)] = value
request_response = getattr(client.service, method)(parameter_object)
print(request_response)
```

As you can notice, the mistake was in this line:

```py
request_response = getattr(client.service, method)(parameter_object)
```

in wich the "parameter_object" dicitonary that contains the request values was missing.